# How to combine overlapping ImageView, FrameLayout & RelativeLayout programatically?

Tags: android, imageview, android-camera, android-relativelayout

i need to combine 3 layouts

the `bottom is ImageView, above it there is a FrameLayout and above it there is a RelativeLayout.`

The `ImageView` takes the `picture from camera`.
The `FrameLayout` is used to `draw lines(PaintView)`.
The `RelativeLayout` is used to `drag small images` to the screen from the side.

The layouts and imageViews are done in xml.

while taking the picture it should combine all the above layouts programmatically to make 1 jpg file.

Progress: .jpg file of ImageView is created.

Stuck: Combining the layouts.

Thanks a lot in Advance.

here is my XML

```
         xml
enter code here


  <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/parentFrameLayout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <android.view.SurfaceView
  android:id="@+id/preview"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >
  </android.view.SurfaceView>

  <FrameLayout
  android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <RelativeLayout
  android:id="@+id/root"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/capIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/cap" />

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/glasses"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/eye_glasses" />

  </RelativeLayout>
  </FrameLayout>
  </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Post your code to show, how you aligned them.

Comment: @gautambib can u pls share how u have achieved ur task can u pls share how u have done ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's a little complicated as you want to print the screen

Answer (score 0):

i will check the following the example working fine. You can try this

https://github.com/SeptiyanAndika/Camera-Overlay-Android